# Proof of $\frac{d}{dz}e^z=e^z$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to prove $\frac{d}{dz}e^z=e^z$ using $ e^z={e^x}{(\cos y+i\sin y)}$?

I can take the derivative of the left hand side with respect to z, but what can I do about right hand side?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cauchy-RiemannEquations.html

Comment: Show that $u(x,y)=e^x\cos y$ and $v(x,y)=e^x\sin y$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equation, then just compute $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$.

Comment: It also depends on what you know about the real functions $e^x$, $\cos x$ and $\sin x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(z) = e^z = {e^x}{(\cos y+i\sin y)} = e^x\cos y + i e^x\sin y = u+iv$$
$$f'(z) = u_x+iv_x = v_y-iu_y=\cdots$$